# Is there a way to detect scroll event of UITableView inside the tableView class itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

The common way to detect if a table was scrolled is to have another class that conformes to `UIScrollViewDelegate` with the following implementation.

```
scrollViewDidScroll:
```

But is there a way to get notified inside the subclassed UITableView that it was scrolled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override method:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset
{
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make your table view subclass  the delegate of the scroll view and it will then be notified of scroll events.

But this isn't really recommended as you should make the table view's controller be the delegate. It's hard to be more specific as you haven't said what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to differentiate table view or scroll view or collection view scrolling, you can do like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(scrollView.tag)
    if scrollView.tag == 0 {
        //hideView()   
    }    
}
```

Comment: func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print(scrollView.tag)
        print(scrollView.tag)
        
        if scrollView.tag == 0 {
        if scrollView.tag == 0 {
            
//           hideView()
            
            //hideView()   
        }
        
        }    
    }     }